# SQL - Recursively finding count in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has both category and subcategory such as this :

```
CategoryID     CategoryName  ParentCategoryID
   1              CatA           NULL
   2              CatA1           1
   3              CatA2           1
   4              CatA3           1
   5              CatB           NULL
   6              CatB1           5
   7              CatC           NULL
   8              CatC1           7
```

I have another table where I have mappings

```
MappingID     CategoryID     ItemID
   1              2            1
   2              3            1
   3              6            2
   4              8            3
   5              2            3
   6              3            4
   7              4            4
   8              2            3
   9              3            4
   10              2            2
   11              2            2
   12              2            2
   13              2            3
   14              2            1
```

I need a result set where count of all items per category is displayed such as :

```
Category    No. of Items
   1            12
   5            1
   7            1
```

Could you someone guide me with this?

I have tried using a CTE :

```
WITH CTE (CategoryID, CategoryName, ParentID, CategoryParentName)
AS
(
    SELECT      CategoryID,
                CategoryName,
                ParentCategoryID,
                CategoryName AS CategoryParentName
    FROM        [dbo].[Category]
    WHERE       ParentCategoryID IS NULL
    AND         IsDeleted = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      garages.CategoryID,
                garages.CategoryName,
                garages.ParentCategoryID,
                traces.CategoryName AS CategoryParentName
    FROM        [dbo].[Category] AS garages
    INNER JOIN  CTE AS traces  ON traces.CategoryID= garages.ParentCategoryID
)

SELECT          gr.CategoryID, COUNT(map.CategoryID) AS Total
FROM            CTE gr
INNER JOIN      [dbo].[CategoryMapping] map ON gr.CategoryID = map.CategoryID
GROUP BY        gr.CategoryID
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are just two levels of categories than there is no need for recursive query

```
select coalesce(c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID), count(*)
from Category c
join CategoryMapping m on c.CategoryID = m.CategoryID 
group by coalesce(c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID)
```

Obviously, categories without mapping won't be there.